# IBM Netezza - tables used by a procedure

Tags: sql, db2, netezza

Does Netezza store table->procedure dependecy metadata?
I trying to compose a query that would return such data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, a procedure is dynamic.  So it could build a list on the fly of the tables it wants to act upon.  Which could be 10 tables one time, and 1000 different tables the next time.  So trying to "parse the SP" would be (a) very, very hard and (b) not conclusive.

So likely you would be best running the procedure and using the query history database and see what tables are used there on a given run of the procedure